# Trigger a jenkins from another in pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to trigger a Jenkins job B from another Jenkins Job A. However the Jenkins Job B should be triggered only after 10 mins and I should not wait in Job A as i will hold the resources that will be used by other jobs.

So the scenario is

"Job A" --> after 10 mins --> "Trigger Job B"

I have to write a pipeline script for this. Please can someone help me with any solution or if you have any alternate solutions please guide.

Comment: If you have a pipeline script which does not allocate a node but only trigger a build it will not allocate any resources. Would that be an option?

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
def job = build job: 'say-hello', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'who', value: 'DZone Readers']], wait: false
```